# Simple static website can interact with database?

Tags: database, static, web-deployment, cdn

Let's say that I would like to build a very simple website which retrives the content from a database but instead of building a dynamic site, which should be deployed in a VPS or a PaaS I want it to be static so it can easily run in any kind of web hosting.
Is that possible? Maybe using a CDN library like axios or jquery?

Thanks!

Comment: Once you use a database, the site isn't static anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Since static Web pages contain fixed code, the content of each page does not change unless it is manually updated by the webmaster. So what you asked for is not a static website.

You need to use at least one server-side programming language (like PHP) to make a connection to a database.

And about compatibility, you don't need to look around VPS or PaaS at the start point, depended on your PL (programming language) and database you can choose your web hosting service from shared hosting providers, as your website growing and you learn more about the web stacks you can think about the dedicated host on VPS or use cloud service and ...

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could do this with static data files. I'm currently trying to develop this for several of my sites. I plan on saving the data in XML files, then dynamically load it via javascript based on the url. By storing the data in text files I can reduce the storage because each page does not need to be formatted beforehand. I'm using a less efficient way of doing this at https://SystematicTheology.us, where the text is stored in data files, but in this case loaded and process by PHP (no completely static, but I could have just as easily done it in Javascript) however the Bible verse references are loaded from another site and added as pop ups. I think the techical term for this is flat-file database.

Comment: XML files are NOT Flat-file Databases. XML files are well structured and organised files where as flat-files are files such as txt or CVS which are not well structured or organised.

Depending on the size of the XML file as well you will potentially hit performance issues later down the line.